# Gradle cannot resolve all dependencies, custom maven url in library

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm using Crashlytics, which provides a custom Maven url. I'm trying to move the Crashlytics code to a library.

The library `build.gradle` file is as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
}
```

When building this library project on its own, all goes well.
However, when I add the library as a dependency to another project, gradle sync only succeeds when I add the custom maven url to its `build.gradle` as well. Otherwise, the following message shows up:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':MyApp'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':MyApp:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+.
     Required by:
         my-app:MyApp:unspecified > my-app:MyLibrary:unspecified
```

Why do I need to add the `maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }` to the `MyApp` project as well? Is there a better solution?

Comment: It's the expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks, @Peter! Should it be expected behavior? What's the philosophy behind it?

Comment: The basic idea is that each build should explicitly state, and have full control over, the repositories that it uses. That's probably also why having repository declarations in published Maven POMs is heavily discouraged nowadays (even in the Maven community), and why Gradle doesn't even try to use that information.